# Pycharm 4.0.3 crash any PyQt program while using Debug

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt5

While debug any `PyQt5` program using Pycharm 4.0.3, it crashes the Python.exe process.

Initially, it shows the `self` variable just fine.

[image]

After you click the `+` at the left of `self`, it shows 'Collecting data':
[image]

And then crash the Python.exe immediately, printing:

```
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 62848 --file D:/My_Program/PyQt/TLC_Python34/TLC_Processor_Py34.py
pydev debugger: process 7536 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 139.781)

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I found several similar reports on google but I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found in File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger that PyQt box was checked. Unchecking it solves the problem.
To solve the problem for every program, do the same in File > Default settings > (...).

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar problem and solved by removing PySide from the virtualenv. It seems that they don't like to work together (PyQt5 and PySide).