# How to debug PyQt4-based application?

Tags: python, debugging, pyqt, pycharm

I have a simple `PyQt4`-based application. I want to debug it with PyCharm.

Alas, I it crashes with an error:

`Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)`

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
win = QtGui.QMainWindow() # Breakpoint is here
win.show()
QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Cannot you tell me, what should I do to cope with it?

Comment: Report it on the [PyCharm bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY). It seems to be a [quite common problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29326171/984421).

Answer (score 6):

I found in `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger` that PyQt box was checked. Unchecking it solves the problem. To solve the problem for every program, do the same in `File > Default settings > (...)`.

Comment: I am using PySide instead of PyQt4 directly, so in all my imports I replace PyQt4 with PySide. My application will run without error under PyCharm (community edition 2017.1) in normal execution mode, but crashes when run in debug mode with the error: SignalInstance() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given). @Delaco - this setting also corrects my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Removing PySide from the virtualenv solved the problem for me.