# Is there a way to automatically install required packages in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Node.js, for a project we create a package.json file, which lists all the dependencies, so that NPM can automatically install them.

Is there an equivalent way to do this with Python ?

Comment: Whichever method you choose to use for installation (conda, freeze, setup.py), use virtual environments. It will make your installation life so, so much better.

Comment: @SteveJ I am using PyCharms virtual environment. But the problem is the Python debugger seems to crash because of something to do with PyQt. The only alternative seems to be to work without PyCharm, which means I either use another IDE / debugger, or switch to using the terminal and installing all the dependencies globally... Or am I not understanding something ?

Comment: @KaizerSozay [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326171/pycharm-4-0-3-crash-any-pyqt-program-wile-debug) may be useful for that PyQt crash issue in Pycharm.

Comment: @Kaizer; I'd suggest two things. 1) File a bug with PyCharm -- they are really on top of it. 2) Since PyCharm creates a virtual environment for you, all you need to do is run it from the virtual environment in the terminal. You don't need to reinstall anything.

Comment: @KaizerSozay; Adding to my previous, if PyCharm has created a virtual environment, then that virtual environment has all the needed packages installed. All you have to do is activate the virtual environment from the terminal. The trick is that there are now two types of virtual environments 1) virtualenv / virtualenvwrapper, 2) pyvenv (now just venv). Read the docs on how to activate an environment from the terminal. In one case it is "workon <envname>". In the other it is "source venv/bin/activate" (Linux)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node has `npm` similarly python having **pip**

> pip is a package management system used to install and manage software
>   packages written in Python.

So first you need to install pip,

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

You have to keep your requirements in `requirements.txt` in you project folder as like `package.json` in `nodejs`.

eg:

```
pip install package1
pip install package2
pip install package3
```

Then move on to your project path, then do this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate dependencies list, and use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all dependencies.

Comment: Node.js is the same, run `npm install --save` to keep it in `package.json`. Or it's ok if you generate the `package.json` file manually.

Comment: I reccommend to use `pipenv` to manage your python dependencies. Refer it [here](https://docs.pipenv.org/)

Comment: npm install --save will keep after dependencies has been installed. your in initial stage you dont know how to install and nothing in it. so `pip freeze` only list default package like `six` `wsgi` if its django thats it..

Comment: I am using a virtual environment in Pycharm. Is there a way to export the packages I have installed via pycharm ?

Comment: you can able to view from settings-> project interpreter. if you want to export,  then open terminal then follow @LuCima answer, pip freeze > requirements.txt

Answer (score 3):

`pip` is available with Python by default in most cases. It is the most common tool used for installing python packages. When authors publish Python packages, they include project metadata (like a `setup.py`, `setup.cfg`, or `pypoject.toml` file) that, in part, declares dependencies of a package so packaging tools like `pip` can resolve the dependencies when you install packages. Some projects may also include one or more `requirements.txt` files in their source which you can direct `pip` to gather the required packages IE `pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt`

Typically speaking, almost all packages you might use are published in the PyPI repository and you merely need to do `pip install <package name>` and pip will resolve all the required dependencies.

There are other tools available as well, which feature things like lockfiles that more closely resemble nodejs lockfiles. [`pipenv`](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) is one tool [recommended by PyPA](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/#managing-dependencies) for installing packages and managing dependencies. It bundles features similar to those found in related tools like virtualenv, pipfile, and more. It also gives you similar features to tools in the JavaScript world, such as `npm`, `yarn`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `conda` by

```
conda install --file requirements.txt
```

Comment: python have its own package installer called `pip`

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a standalone library, consider using [`setuptools`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and define a `setup.py` with an `install_requires` field for the dependencies required for the library.  Example:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='example.package',
    install_requires=[
        'setuptools',
        'requests>=3.0.0',
        # other requirements
    ],
    # ... and other attributes
)
```

If you are trying to produce a development/build environment, a `requirements.txt` can be sufficient, but this is not available to other Python packages through the standard dependency resolution.

See [`install_requires` vs. Requirement files](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/)

Also, please reference the [Python packaging guide](https://packaging.python.org/) for a more comprehensive set of information on how to work with packages, e.g. [installation of package](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) (covers the usage of pip, virtualenv which is useful for setting up a development environment), [producing a package](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/) that can be distributed (covers what to put in a project's `setup.py`).

Answer (score 2):

The quickest and best way that I've found when delivering a program that has dependencies uses a few simple steps.

1. Use `pip install pipreqs` that allows running `pipreqs /--directory to your program folder--/` and produces the requirements.txt file inside your program's folder for your program that lists all package dependencies.
2. Copy/paste the folders containing package dependencies from where ever your python packages are downloaded to (eg..\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages) straight into the folder for your program.
3. Run `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt` and run the program to make sure it still works without the dependencies installed.