# PyCharm and Pyqtgraph: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I can run this code in Pycharm in a standard Python Console of a clean project:

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

data = np.random.normal(size=1000)
pg.plot(data, title="Simplest possible plotting example")
pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

I was now trying to customize the X axis to support datetime, so I've used this code I've found online:

```
class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setLabel(text='Time', units=None)
        self.enableAutoSIPrefix(False)

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(value).strftime("%H:%M") for value in values]
```

And tried to use it with this:

```
x = np.random.normal(size=10)
y = np.arange(np.datetime64('2017-01-01'), np.datetime64('2017-01-11'))
pg.plot({'x': x, 'y': y}, axisItems={'bottom': TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')})
```

However, this (and many other codes I've found around to display datetime in the X axis) doesn't work. If I launch either from the Python console or from "Run" or "Debug" menu, I get this error:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I've already tried this: [Pycharm 4.0.3 crash any PyQt program while using Debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326171/pycharm-4-0-3-crash-any-pyqt-program-while-using-debug)

Why is this?